# problems with js console output

Tags: javascript

help please with mini-problem :

```js
function sum(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
sum (1, 3);
```

why "function sum" doesn't show a value (4)
if I write "console.log" instead of "return" then all working good, why?
thanks so much

Comment: It does for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vq5ob2Lj/

Comment: It is obvious, with `return` you are returning a value, `console.log()` print this in console. You can use `console.log(sum(1,3));`

Comment: You may be confused because running that code in Developer Tools of your browser will log the return value (at least for Chrome), so this appears very similar to `console.log`, but that only happens when you are in Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [return](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) is used to stop/break a function in execution and send back to the caller a result.

[console.log](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp) is used to print in the console information.

If you want to print the result of your function you can always do this:

```
function sum(a, b) {
return a + b;
}
console.log(sum (1, 3));
```

Comment: and one more question, if we have such construction like this :
(function () {
    function sum(a, b) {
        return a + b;
        // (1, 2) = 3
    })();
how we need to do it? if we can change just body func

Comment: @LikeJavaSCript There's no point in using `return` in an IIFE, the return value isn't used unless you assign it or pass it as an argument, like `console.log(function () { function sum(a, b) { return a + b; // (1, 2) = 3 })())`.